# npm ERR! code ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID

Tags: angular, npm

It had been a while since I tried setting up a new Angular app -- because I've been working on an existing one for several months.

Today, upon trying to install a new Angular app via the terminal in my Mac, it ran really slowly, and then resulted in this err:

> npm ERR! code ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID
>
> npm ERR! Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host:
>   registry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert's altnames:
>   DNS:a.sni.fastly.net, DNS:a.sni.global-ssl.fastly.net

How do I address this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

run `npm config set strict-ssl false` and re-run `ng new appName`

if it doesn't work try to run `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"`

**Edit**

> An earlier outage involving a DNS misconfiguration has lead to some ISPs caching npmjs.com as missing, a workaround for this is to use a third party DNS provider such as Cloudflare or Google, the affected caches should clear within the next 24 hours.

https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/v22ffls5cd6h

Comment: @Ayoub_k, I tried, `npm config set strict-ssl false` and it produced this error: `registry error parsing json`. So then I tried `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` and got the same error again. Ideas?

Comment: i think your npm version is too old. run `npm cache clean`  and `npm install npm -g` after that try to run one of the commands in the answer.

Comment: Okay, will try that. Thanks.

Comment: `Muir-Air:~ muir$ sudo npm cache clean
Password: ************
Muir-Air:~ muir$ sudo npm install npm -g
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠹ normalizeTree: ERR! registry error parsing json`

Comment: try : `sudo npm cache clean --force`

Comment: here's some suggestion, one of them may works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787702/npm-err-registry-error-parsing-json-while-trying-to-install-cordova-for-ionic and https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8536

Comment: It seems a npm related issue, check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128026/npm-died-completely-err-tls-cert-altname-invalid-hostname-ip-does-not-match-ce/52129462#52129462

Comment: Thanks, @Ayoub. As you suggested in your last edit, it does seem like this problem resolved on its own. By the end of the day the problem seemed to have resolved itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think its npmjs DNS Problem now

Try adding

104.16.16.35 registry.npmjs.org

to your etc\host file with admin right using notepad

Remove it when it is resolved

Comment: I think you could be right. How do I get to the host file you mention here?

Comment: According to [NPM's status page](https://status.npmjs.org/). They are having DNS issues and recommend this.

Comment: @Muirik on windows C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Answer (score 0):

npm config set strict-ssl false
Work for me fine

Answer (score -1):

yes it is working.

MAC => vim /etc/hosts

Thanks