# ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID fastly compilation error for iOS release build

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, fastly

I have a React Native app, I ejected from Expo, and I now have a Bare Workflow.
When I try to compile an iOS Release build I have the following error:

```
Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: assets. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:fastly.net, DNS:www.fastly.net
Before making a release build, make sure you have run 'expo publish' at least once. Learn more. (​https://expo.fyi/release-builds-with-expo-updates​)
```

Do you have any idea why fastly is here and how to fix this? I tried following [this npm bugfix](https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/v22ffls5cd6h), but it does not work.

Comment: Looks like an NPM DNS caching issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129123/14849316

Comment: @Integralist I tried that but it does not work unfortunately